# Multiple 'nibs' per UIViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, controller, uiimageview, segue

I'm using storyboards and I want two UIViewControllers to share the same controller class. I've done this and I've hooked up my UIImageViews to their IBOutlets.

When I call `[day3 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"1.png"]];`

it doesn't change the image. Has this got anything to do with it sharing the same controller class as another view?

This view with the UIImageViews on is opened via push segue from the other view controlled by the same controller class.

Comment: No, that shouldn't be a problem since they are different instances. Try logging days3 and [UIImage imageNamed: @"1.png"] to see if either is nil.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that although both views are using the same UIViewController, they are connected to different instances of them. Let's call our ViewController myViewController. When the new view is pushed it actually creates a whole new myViewController. So you now have two active in your app. One instance of myViewController for the first view and another for the second view. You can therefore not directly manipulate the views from the other view's instance of that controller.

In order to set properties you will need to communicate between the two instances of myViewController the same way you would as if they were entirely different ViewControllers. If you need further help or explanation let me know.